# Is there a simple way to replace non numeric characters hive excluding - to allow only -ve and +ve numbers

Tags: regex, hive

The following will give me 9090 but I wish to get -9090

```
regexp_replace('abcd-9090',[^0-9],'')
```

If I use `regexp_replace('abcd-9090',[^0-9-],'')`
then it gives -9090
but when the string is `abcd9090-` it would give me `9090-`

There could be many more cases I guess where `abc-abcd-9090` would give me `-9090` but its safe to assume that such will not be the case and there would be only a single `-` before the numeric values.

Since there could be many cases , I am just supposed to assume the best and  replace the flawed code with a more correct pattern which produces an integer almost always.

May be like assuming a condition where only single `-` could come at the beginning of any digits in the string is okay to assume.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what if you have a string like `abcd-9090-1`..what should be the output in cases like these?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Even if I come with a condition where we just allow an occurrence of single hifen -, may be using something like `-?` at the start of numeric value would be fine. and in the rest the hifen is discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try to use `regexp_extract` instead:

`regexp_extract('abcd-9090','.*(-[0-9]+)',1)`

UPD from comment - author need to address one more corner case:

`regexp_extract(regexp_replace('-ab2cd9090','[^\\d-]+',''),'(-?\\d+)',1)`

Comment: Yes may be two regex functions are needed instead. `regexp_extract(regexp_replace('-ab2cd9090','[^\\d-]+',''),'(-?\\d+)',1)` . You can post that as an answer.